# Gurobi Equivalent of `CPX_PARAM_ALL_MIN` and `CPX_PARAM_ALL_MAX`

Tags: gurobi

I am trying to find if there are any equivalents of `CPX_PARAM_ALL_MIN` and `CPX_PARAM_ALL_MAX`.

I am trying to port some code from CPLEX to GuRoBi

and there is some code like this

```
for (int i = CPX_PARAM_ALL_MIN; i <= CPX_PARAM_ALL_MAX; ++i)
{
         stat = CPXgetparamname(env, i, name);
}
```

while I found out that `CPXgetparamname` equivalent is `GRBgetparamname`, I am unable to find the equivalents of CPX_PARAM_ALL_MIN and CPX_PARAM_ALL_MAX

Answer (score 0):

Not all features map directly between Gurobi and CPLEX; this is one example. Here, CPLEX parameters are indexed by a number, while Gurobi parameters are indexed by a string (char* in C). If you want to get the full list of Gurobi parameters programmatically, look at the Parameters section in the header file include/gurobi_c.h.